# Is there ever a reason to use the declare keyword in front of types and interfaces?

Tags: typescript, declare

I have come across some code like this:

```
declare type A = { ... };
declare interface B { ... }
```

From searching for the `declare` keyword (and none of the hits pointed to me the TypeScript docs for some reason), `declare` is used when a variable exists in JavaScript and you need to reference it from TypeScript, so you declare to the compiler that this variable indeed exists.

All examples I have found that use this keyword use it like this: `declare var a;`

Why would I ever use it in front of a `type` or `interface`? Based on my understanding of `declare`, it is completely useless to do so, but the compiler doesn't give me any errors.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks like I just found out why.

From this github [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1940):

> `declare` should be optional on type aliases and interfaces.
>
> `declare type` and `declare interface` are identical to `type` and `interface`
>
> Since we already shipped type aliases this way, people have had to write `declare type` a bunch of times. We could break them and say "Write `type`, not `declare type`", but that would be a massive break for no real reason.

In summary, there is no reason to use `declare` for types and interfaces.

Comment: What about namespaces?

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk namespaces are a legitimate TS thing. see [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-namespace)