# typescript: cant declare an interface

Tags: typescript, declaration, typescript-typings

I'm using typescript and not able to use the declared interfaces from another file.
My `global.d.ts` looks like this.

```
declare interface IPropSendEmail {
    from: string,
    to: string,
    subject: string,
    html: string,
}
```

below is tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "./build",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "strict": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "types"
        ],
    }
}
```

the directory structure looks like this

```
    | -- src
            |-- types
                     |-- global.d.ts
            |-- util
                     |-- common.ts
            |-- ...
```

using it in `common.ts` file

```
export async function sendEmail({ from, to, subject, html }: IPropSendEmail) {
     // function code here
     ...
}
```

Comment: This is not enough information for us, please provide more context (e.g., what other file, how are you trying to use it, etc).

Answer (score 2):

It should work. However, I suggest to clean the weird part of your configuration:

In your `tsconfig.json`:

- Remove `typeRoots`;
- Add `include`.

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "build",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "strict": true
    },
    "include": ["src"]
}
```

In `global.d.ts`, the keyword `declare` is useless:

```
interface IPropSendEmail {
    from: string,
    to: string,
    subject: string,
    html: string,
}
```

Ensure there is no `export` or `import` in this file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and suggestions for tsconfig.json. I have used `declare` so that I can use that `interface` in any file without importing it. I've used it previously it's just I don't have that configuration now.

Comment: @mkamranhamid Just try to remove it (the `declare` keyword). It'll work the same way.

Comment: I think you're referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233987/how-to-configure-custom-global-interfaces-d-ts-files-for-typescript) by @Andris. This is a very detailed answer on why using `declare` is a bad practice.

Comment: @mkamranhamid No, I'm really saying that the keyword `declare` is useless with an interface.

Comment: then? are you saying I should use `export` so that the `interface` will be available to `import` in `common.ts`

Comment: @mkamranhamid I suggest you read the text on the lines and stop reading between the lines. Seriously! https://stackoverflow.com/a/49156180/3786294

Comment: I did that thing but It didn't work. To make it work I have to remove all imports statements from `common.ts` as suggested by [@Andris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233987/how-to-configure-custom-global-interfaces-d-ts-files-for-typescript)

Comment: @mkamranhamid It works. I just tried. And nobody suggested to remove all imports from `common.ts`.